# Can't find a way to click on an href link with selenium (Python 3.7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

[Pic of inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWW6H.jpg)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://website.com/')
driver.maximize_window()
search = driver.find_element_by_id('UserName')
search.send_keys('UserName')
search = driver.find_element_by_id('Password')
search.send_keys('Password')
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Admin"))
    )
    element.click
    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Admin')
    link.click()
    
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Reports"))
    )
    element.click
    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Reports')
    link.click()
    
except:
    driver.quit()
    
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
sales_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sales').click()
```

Below is the info from the website, I want to click on Sales but can't seem to do so any help would be appreciated

a _ngcontent-hyf-c12="" routerlink="./SalesReport" routerlinkactive="active" href="/Reports/SalesReport"Sales /a

[Pic of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNHYh.png)

This what appears if I try to click on it with XPATH
[Error Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pi4IK.jpg)

Comment: Can you share the link to the website? so we can verify

Comment: better show real URL for this page - and then we can see what is the problem.

Comment: if element is inside `<frame>` then it may need `switch_to.frame()`

Comment: first you could remove `try/except` to see full error message - it helps to understand problem.

Comment: Sorry can't show full url as this is for work.

Comment: I'm also debating whether to use href or text text to click on the link I want. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: I see there is a space after Sales try `driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sales ').click()` (note the extra space after Sales)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html pic, I see a whitespace after Sales.
Look carefully: `href="/Reports/SalesReport">Sales </a`.

So `find_element_by_link_text('Sales')` will not work.
You can change it to `find_element_by_link_text('Sales ')`.

However, this will be better:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Sales')]")
```

Comment: If the answer is useful, please click the Upward triangle in front of this answer : ) else let me know, I'll do my best to change it again.